# Mocking HttpClient requests with mockito

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, httpclient, unknown-host

I have the following code that I wish to test using Junit and Mockito.

Code to test:

```
    Header header = new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,AUTH_PREAMBLE + token);
    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
    headers.add(header);
    HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultHeaders(headers).build();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("real REST API here"));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
    String json_string_response = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

And the Test

```
protected static HttpClient mockHttpClient;
protected static HttpGet mockHttpGet;
protected static HttpResponse mockHttpResponse;
protected static StatusLine mockStatusLine;
protected static HttpEntity mockHttpEntity;





@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    mockHttpGet = Mockito.mock(HttpGet.class);
    mockHttpClient = Mockito.mock(HttpClient.class);
    mockHttpResponse = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);
    mockStatusLine = Mockito.mock(StatusLine.class);
    mockHttpEntity = Mockito.mock(HttpEntity.class);

    Mockito.when(mockHttpClient.execute(Mockito.isA(HttpGet.class))).thenReturn(mockHttpResponse);
    Mockito.when(mockHttpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(mockStatusLine);
    Mockito.when(mockStatusLine.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
    Mockito.when(mockHttpResponse.getEntity()).thenReturn(mockHttpEntity);

}


@Test
underTest = new UnderTest(initialize with fake API (api));
//Trigger method to test
```

This gives me an error:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: api: nodename nor servname provided, or
>   not known

Why does t not mock the `'client.execute(get)'` call as is in the set up?

Comment: You are right in that it is executing the real network stuff. Is this expected after mocking a the client and the get request? Shouldnt it just return an object of type HttpResponse without making the actual network call?

Comment: Is there a way to activate these mocks? My confusion is how to activate the mocks when the code yries to initialize these objects

Comment: @user_mda I am also facing same problem, if you have came out of this problem, can u plz help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have so far is:

```
mockHttpClient = Mockito.mock(HttpClient.class);
Mockito.when(mockHttpClient.execute(Mockito.isA(HttpGet.class))).thenReturn(mockHttpResponse)
```

So there is a *mock* that should react to a call to `execute()`.

And then you have:

```
1) underTest = new UnderTest(initialize with fake API (api));
2) // Trigger method to test
```

The problem is: something is either wrong with your line 1 or with line 2 in your setup. But **we can not** tell you that; because you are not providing that code to us.

The thing is: in order for your **mock** object to be of use, it needs to be **used** by *underTest* somehow. So when you are doing the init stuff wrong somehow, then underTest is not using the mocked thing, but some "real" thing.